# Dropdown is not showing HTML , CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have the attr data-toggle= dropdown on the {{form.query}} which is the search input

but it just wont show, any solutions?

bootstrap/jquery links in head section :

```
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JavaScript in body :

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

HTML code:

```
<form class="dropdown" method="get">
       <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here" data-toggle="dropdown" required id="id_query">
    
       <ul class="dropdown-menu col-12 pl-2" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu" id="list" style="display:inline-block;">
          <li role="presentation"> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Django</a></li>
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
           <li role="presentation"> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Potato</a></li>
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
           <li role="presentation"> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Sleep</a></li>
       </ul> 
    
   <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-12 my-2">                    
</form>
```

Comment: its applying display none for the ul class

Comment: Please show the fully rendered html, after `{{form.query}}` has been parsed

Comment: thank you they showed now, but now they are showing on the page as soon as it refreshes without the dropdown working

Comment: i edited the code to show the {{form.query}}

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. You have to add

`id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"` in `input`

and

`aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"` in `dropdown-menu`

as per bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/)

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/8fnw0o46/11/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="dropdown" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" required id="id_query">

  <ul class="dropdown-menu col-12 pl-2" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="list">
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Django</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Potato</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Sleep</a></li>
  </ul>

  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-12 my-2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use ether a link or a button to toggle the dropdown, not a text input.

> Wrap the dropdown’s toggle (your button or link) and the dropdown menu
> within .dropdown, or another element that declares position:
> relative;. Dropdowns can be triggered from `<a>` or `<button>` elements to
> better fit your potential needs.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/#examples

Comment: yes i actually read that, but im following a tutorial and the guy did it on the text input field

Comment: Then ask that guy, or re-read the tutorial, I'm guessing they added some javascript.

Comment: style="
    transform: translate3d(px, 37px, 0px);
    position: absolute;
    will-change: transform;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; // i got his code from github and he had these extra styles but it still didnt work